# Adding border-bottom to nav and vertical align menu items

Tags: html, css, border, nav

I have a navigation that worked fine when i didn't use any custom bottom border on the nav links, but trying to adding them and still have the functionality as before does my head in. I just want to vertical align the nav items with 50px height and a custom border on the menu links, but keep it functional when in mobile size and de border in mobile view is replaced with a normal underline declaration.

This what i had before adding a custom bottom border and it works:

[--> Fiddle before](https://jsfiddle.net/foroloca/q2dxojss/10/)

And this is what happens when adding a custom bottom border when in mobile size the menu items don't vertical align and the background doesn't go down with them:

[--> Fiddle after](https://jsfiddle.net/foroloca/7vtmbgkx/)

```
<header>
<nav>
    <div class="mobile-nav">
        <div class="nav-toggle"><i class="nav-icon"></i></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="left-nav">   
        <li class="home"><a href="#">Pixelation</a></li>    
    </ul>
    <ul class="right-nav">  
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/Screetop/23171e9e/ Added a min-height on your nav element.

Comment: **Bilingual moderator note**: Leuk he, zo lekker in je eigen taal babbelen? Maar als jullie het in het engels zouden doen, dan kunnen andere mensen wellicht ook meehelpen. :-) / *Nice, isn't it, chatting in your own language? But if you held this conversation in English others could help out too, perhaps. :-)*

Comment: You are properly right about that. I was easier to explain and felt a bit weird if you know the other speaks the same language to continue in English.